# Why does Explorer keep SMB connections open, even If I specifically tell it to close it?

Tags: windows, networking, smb

I have two Servers, Server A and Server B.

I connected from Server A to Server B through explorer via UNC like so `\\ServerB\d$` and was prompted for a Username & Password. I entered my credentials and was connected.

However, I have a scheduled task that runs a PowerShell Script which creates a `PSDrive` as **another User** than I used in my connection before. Which makes my script go (as expected of course):

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-PSDrive -Name Test -Root \\ServerB\SomeShare -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential (Get-Credential)

New-PSDrive : Multiple connections to a server or shared resource from the same user using multiple usernames are not allowed. 
Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name Test -Root \\ServerB\SomeShare -PSProvider FileSystem -Cred ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Test:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

I was trying to delete this earlier connection without rebooting my ServerA or logging out my logged on user of ServerA. through `netstat -n | findstr :445` I found that PID 4 is using this connection (which was explorer.exe) and could successfully eliminate it via `taskkill /im explorer.exe /f && start "" explorer.exe`.

However before that, I tried these two things:

1. From ServerA: `Get-SmbConnection -ServerName ServerB | Close-SmbSession -Force` - This runs without any error message, but the SMB Connection is still there
2. Good old : `net use \\serverb\d$ /del` ran successfully, but didn't help, I still can't use another user to connect to the ressource

I'm curious why does `explorer.exe` keep the SMB Connections open, even If I specifically tell it to close it? Is there a way to close it without restarting `explorer.exe`?

Comment: Explorer does not actually make SMB connections IIRC, that’s something higher-privileged services handle. // Did you try using `net use \\pcname\ipc$ /del` yet?

Comment: if you connect by hostname or by ipaddress, they are seem as different connections. so if one user uses \\pcname\... and the other user uses \\192.168.x.x then windows will not complain.

Comment: also, if the network connection has a drivemap, I find that `mountvol x: /d` will remove connections even net use can't.

Comment: imo, the question that is linked as a duplicate does not really have a satisfying answer to my question. I would like to know why Explorer keeps the Connections open (or whatever else keeps the connection open)and how to close one single connection, not all of them. The (unaccepted) answer of the duplicate question is about killing everything by restarting a service